# cast variable to int vs round() function

Tags: c, int, rounding

I have seen it in several places where `(int)someValue` has been inaccurate and instead the problem called for the `round()` function. What is the difference between the two?

Specifically, if need be, for C99 C. I have also seen the same issue in my programs when writing them in java.

Comment: Also interesting thing I never heard before: "Round to nearest even is the default IEEE rounding mode." - https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2014/01/27/theres-only-four-billion-floatsso-test-them-all/

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In case of casting a `float`/`double` value to `int`, you generally loose the *fractional* part due to **integer truncation**.

This is quite different from rounding as we would usually expect, so for instance 2.8 ends up as 2 with integer truncation, just as 2.1 would end up as 2.

*Update*:

Another source of potential (gross) inaccuracy with casting is due to the limited range of values being able to be represented with integers as opposed to with floating point types (thanks to @R reminding us about this in the comment below)

Comment: I don't understand why these problem sets(compeition or for harvard's online cs50) use round() and tell the students specifically to use int so that they round _down_. That's pretty annoying don't you think? Anyways, thank you.

Comment: Another issue with casting or implicitly converting to an integer is that large-magnitude values are destroyed. Even when you want a whole-number result, it's often best to keep a floating-point type so large-magnitude numbers are preserved. Functions like `round`, `floor`, `rint`, etc. can do this.

Comment: @r *excellent* point, the range of values being able to be represented is definitely limited with integers. I think I will add a note about this to my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @R.. - absolutely correct point, but what does it have to do with the subject matter? This "problem" (not really. It is a feature) is not resolved by the use of `round()` over casting. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 16):

1. Casting to `int` truncates a floating-point number, that is, it drops the fractional part.
2. The `round` function returns the nearest integer. Halfway cases are rounded away from zero, for example, `round(-1.5)` is `-2` and `round(1.5)` is `2`.

> **7.12.9.6 The round functions**
>
> **Synopsis**
>
> ```
> #include <math.h>
> double round(double x);
> float roundf(float x);
> long double roundl(long double x);
> ```
>
> **Description**
>
> The `round` functions round their argument to the nearest
>   integer value in floating-point format, rounding halfway cases away
>   from zero, regardless of the current rounding direction.
>
> **Returns**
>
> The `round` functions return the rounded integer value.

Source: the C99 standard ([ISO/IEC 9899:1999](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)). This section did not change in the C11 standard ([ISO/IEC 9899:2011](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)).

(For those who are interested, [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130402193401/http://www.diycalculator.com/popup-m-round.shtml) is a clear introduction to rounding algorithms.)

Comment: Just a note, rounding behavior may vary from the expected and by language. E.g., I recently discovered that Python 3.x rounds toward the nearest *even* number .. which really threw me off. So, it's always good to check the documentation. I believe from my C programming days that C's behavior is more in line with common expectations.

Comment: Yup, totally surprised me too. It's referred to as "Banker's rounding".

Comment: The standard load-float instruction in x86 also rounds rather than truncates. You have to change the rounding mode of the FPU to get the behaviour required by C.

Comment: `round` does not perform round-to-nearest (aka banker's rounding). Instead of does naive grade-school round-half-away-from-zero rounding, which is almost always the wrong thing to do for any legitimate use of floating point arithmetic.

Comment: @R.. I included the specification of the round function from the C99 standard. It says clearly what round *should* do.

Comment: Perhaps you can also cite the section "6.3.1.4 Real floating and integer", clause 1 of the C99 standard, that specifies the truncate behavior when a floating point is cast to `int`. _"When a finite value of real floating type is converted to an integer type other than `_Bool`, the fractional part is discarded (i.e., the value is truncated toward zero). If the value of the integral part cannot be represented by the integer type, the behavior is undefined."_